Show android overlay on current activity without overlay permission
Is it possible to display an overlay in my Activity without the android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission?
The overlay should only cover part of the screen, but it should be possible to click on the main activity outside the overlay. It should also be possible to attach it to any Activity without modifying the existing Activity. A Dialog or AlertDialog does not, as far as I know, allow clicking on the activity.
I'm able to display an overlay with a system-level service (e.g. Android Studio - Show Information From Main Activity in Overlay Activity), but how can I display it only on my Activity without the system wide permission?
